# how to modify one column by ascending and descending order in mysql

Tags: mysql

From The Following Mysql Query

```
select (
   case
   when grade < 8 then null 
   else name
   end
   ) as name,
   grade, marks 
from students
join Grades
ON Min_mark = (SELECT MAX(Min_mark) from grades where min_mark <= students.marks)
order by grade desc,name asc
```

I want to sort the order based on the value of grade i.e.

To generate a report containing three columns: Name, Grade and Mark. The report must be in descending order by grade -- i.e. higher grades are entered first. If there is more than one student with the same grade (1-10) assigned to them, order those particular students by their name alphabetically. Finally, if the grade is lower than 8, use "NULL" as their name and list them by their marks in ascending

```
select (
   case
   when grade < 8 then null 
   else name
   end
   ) as name,
   grade, marks 
from students
join Grades
ON Min_mark = (SELECT MAX(Min_mark) from grades where min_mark <= students.marks)
 case
    when grade <8 then 
        order by grade desc, name asc
    else 
        order by marks asc
 end
```

But the second query does not execute because of wrong syntax. Can Someone Please suggest me how to get the required result. Thanks In Advance

Comment: Your order by (while syntactically wrong) is also ambiguous; you don't (and can't as you've structured it) specify whether `grade <= 10` records come before or after the `grade > 10` ones.

Comment: Can you give us more info. What this conditions should do and why? Can you show your database structure(dump tables or even screen)?

Comment: @Arkowsky task to generate a report containing three columns:  Name, Grade and Mark. 
The report must be in descending order by grade -- i.e. higher grades are entered first. 
If there is more than one student with the same grade (1-10) assigned to them, 
order those particular students by their name alphabetically. 
Finally, if the grade is lower than 8, use "NULL" as their name and list them by their marks in ascending order

Comment: What is wrong with `ORDER BY grade DESC, name ASC, marks DESC`? (Aside from perhaps an ambiguity resulting from aliasing with an actual field name; try aliasing and ordering by something like `displayed_name` instead.)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is something like this:

```
ORDER BY grade > 10 DESC /* orders by grade>10 records first */
, CASE WHEN grade > 10 THEN grade ELSE null END DESC /* all grade<=10 records will "sort" equally among themselves */
, CASE WHEN grade > 10 THEN name ELSE marks END ASC /* all grade<=10 records will "sort" by `name`, others will sort my `marks`  */
```

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to sort a query by two different order by clauses.

You can add one or more additional rows to the statement and order by this rows.
To make this, you had to decide how to sort. Should a grade less than 10 come before all grades > 10?

Something like this could work:

```
select (
   case
   when grade < 8 then null 
   else name
   end
   ) as name,
   grade, marks,
   (
   case
   when grade > 10 then grade
   else null
   end
   ) as sortorder1,
   (
   case
   when grade > 10 then name
   else marks
   end
   ) as sortorder2 
from students
join Grades
ON Min_mark = (SELECT MAX(Min_mark) from grades where min_mark <= students.marks)
order by sortorder1 desc, sortorder2 asc
```

**Edit** assumning grades lower than 8 should be sorted by grade as well:

I think this should work:

```
select (
   case
   when grade < 8 then null 
   else name
   end
   ) as displayname,
   grade, marks 
from students
join Grades
ON Min_mark = (SELECT MAX(Min_mark) from grades where min_mark <= students.marks)
order by grade desc, displayname asc, marks asc
```

I replaced the 'as name' by 'as displayname' to make more clear, that the sorting should be done by displayname, I'm not sure wether this is needed for the database but more clear for the humans reading the query.

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/3604523/h-m-i-13 I have modified the question please have a check with that !!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your column names but for me this should be so simple like this:

```
select IF(grade < 8, null, grade) as processed_grade, name 
from students
join Grades
ON students.id = Grades.id_student
order by processed_grade desc,name asc
```

You just change grade to null if is below 8 and then sort records by this new created column and name.